# Is Enterprise-J and Temporal Agent civilization no longer in existence in the future?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

According to [this StarTrek.com article](https://intl.startrek.com/gallery/most-powerful-star-trek-ships-ranked):

> The Enterprise-J deserves a lot of credit. It is one of the ships that helped destroy the galactic threat of the Sphere-Builders in the Battle of Procyon V. The only problem is this timeline may have never come to pass since Captain Jonathan Archer denied the wishes of Temporal Agent Daniels in the Star Trek: Enterprise episode “Azati Prime.” It’s unknown if this ship will ever be built.

Which kind of inference is this? I don't remember all of the details from *Star Trek: Enterprise*, but I can recall clearly that Daniels thanked and congratulated Archer for ending Temporal Cold War. Given, Daniels returned even after multiple deaths thanks to timey-wimey stuff, what can be powerful enough to erase entire temporal agent civilization from existence? And, why would anyone give a 22nd century starship captain an authority to do so?

How much truth is there in the quote?

Comment: What makes you think the organization no longer exists?  The butterfly effect might have changed that this sip was never built, but that a other design or name is used.

Comment: @A.bakker From the quote: `this timeline may have never come to pass`..

Comment: each change would be a completely different timeline.  Even if the only effect this entire event had on the timeline would be one woman coloring her hair blue instead of green it would be a new timeline. Just because the timeline is different with this ship missing doesn't mean that the cold war never happened or that the organizations involved never existed.

Comment: There was a hint at this. DIS S3E3 (now set in the 32nd century) made a big deal about a [USS Voyager (NCC 74656-J)](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-discovery-season-3-voyager-j-ship-explained/). So a "J" ship is canon at least